# Can I retry every SQL query in case of a deadlock exception (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, query, update, deadlock

Is it always safe to retry an SQL query in case of a deadlock exception? Can this lead to unexpected behavior or executing an operation twice? I think a deadlock exception always means a rollback even if the query doesn't run in an explicitly defined transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Understand though, a deadlock is an expensive problem. Every deadlock involves a rollback. A simple retry through TRY/CATCH is a very standard mechanism for dealing with deadlocks. However, it introduces the problem of getting into a loop, so exercise caution.

[Here's an example of how it works](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42547/SQL-SERVER-How-To-Handle-Deadlock). Look at the loop counter example especially. This gets you away from dangerous territory by limiting the number of retries.